# Using both multicolumn and multirow in a table

Tags: tables, multirow, multicolumn

I want to create a table that uses both multicolumn and multirow. Currently, I used the code:

```
\begin{table}[!h]
\label{T:equipos}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{7}{|c|}{\textbf{Datasets}}  \\ 
\cline{1-7}
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\textbf{in-house}} &  \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\textbf{NSL-KDD}} \\
\hline
\hline

DR & Accuracy & FPR & K value & DR & Accuracy & FPR\\ \hline
\multirow{ 1}{*}{99.75} & \multirow{ 1}{*}{99.72} & \multirow{ 1}{*}{0.06} & 

1 & 90.53 & 96.14 & 0.0\\ \hline
&  &  & 2 & 94.22 & 97.65 & 0.0\\ \hline
&  &  & 3 & 95.50 & 98.16 & 0.0\\ \hline
&  &  & 4 & 96.10 & 98.41 & 0.0\\ \hline
&  &  & 5 & 97.7 & 98.92 & 0.11\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

which produces the following table

[image]

but what I want is this:

[image]

how can I achieve the format of the table above i.e., table 2 above?

Comment: Why do you use a 1-row multirow?

Comment: Try sketching your table here, http://www.tablesgenerator.com/. Then just optimize the code for you.

Edit: Also, @TeXnician is right.. 1-row multirow is a no-no.

Comment: @TiagoCorreia But also using a table generator, if the table is nearly correct...

Comment: Yes, not ideal, but it's an idea to try to "debug" any errors made by hand.

Comment: @TiagoCorreia And mostly introducing many pairs of braces that aren't needed...

Comment: @TiagoCorreia Thanks for that generator link. I think in future it will save me a lot of headache

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To be honest: You do not need multirow for that.

[image: multirow]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htb]
\label{T:equipos}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{7}{|c|}{\textbf{Datasets}}  \\ 
\cline{1-7}
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\textbf{in-house}} &  \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\textbf{NSL-KDD}} \\
\hline
\hline
DR & Accuracy & FPR & K value & DR & Accuracy & FPR\\ \hline
99.75 & 99.72 & 0.06 & 1 & 90.53 & 96.14 & 0.0\\ \cline{4-7}
&  &  & 2 & 94.22 & 97.65 & 0.0\\ \cline{4-7}
&  &  & 3 & 95.50 & 98.16 & 0.0\\ \cline{4-7}
&  &  & 4 & 96.10 & 98.41 & 0.0\\ \cline{4-7}
&  &  & 5 & 97.7 & 98.92 & 0.11\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

---

*Update:* You should maybe consider to (a) align your values at the decimal point and (b) use booktabs (just as suggestion):

[image: booktabbed]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htb]
\label{T:equipos}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{SSSlSSS}
\toprule
\multicolumn{7}{c}{\bfseries Datasets}\\
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\bfseries in-house} &  \multicolumn{4}{c}{\bfseries NSL-KDD}\\\cmidrule(lr){1-3}\cmidrule(lr){4-7}
\multicolumn{1}{l}{DR} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Accuracy} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{FPR} & 
  K value & \multicolumn{1}{l}{DR} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Accuracy} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{FPR}\\\midrule
99.75 & 99.72 & 0.06 & 1 & 90.53 & 96.14 & 0.0\\
&  &  & 2 & 94.22 & 97.65 & 0.0\\
&  &  & 3 & 95.50 & 98.16 & 0.0\\
&  &  & 4 & 96.10 & 98.41 & 0.0\\
&  &  & 5 & 97.7 & 98.92 & 0.11\\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```